# How to insert data from functions in new ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, es6-class

can I insert data into arguments from a function?
Instead of having hardcoded values is there a way that I can directly link the arguments to a function which stores all the data?

```
var data;

function data() {
  this.x = 200,
  this.y = 200,
  this.r = 40,
}

b = new Bubble(data); **//IS THIS CORRECT?**

class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, r) { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
    this.y = this.y + random(-5, 5);
  }
  show() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*2);
  }
}
```

Comment: why not return on Object of data from the data() function?

Comment: By hardcoding, do you mean `(x, y, r)` and `this.x = x`?

Comment: ***... IS THIS CORRECT?*** No. `data` should be an object `{x: 200, y: 200, r: 40}`

Comment: @Rajesh I actually want it to link to an object to make things simpler. Instead of - b = new Bubble(200, 400, .....) , i was hoping to write  -  b = new Bubble(data); where a data have x, y stuff in it.

Comment: @NikhilMishra Yup. Already addressed in my answer. You can check. If you have any queries, feel free to add in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty odd way of doing things, but if you change your constructor to:

```
class Bubble {
  constructor(initializerFn) { 
    initializerFn.call(this);
  }
}
```

the function you pass in, `data`, will have `this` set to your new bubble and it'll work.

I've never seen anyone do this before though :)

Comment: I was wondering myself why this set up so oddly... I think the OP is making a mistake with the data function and data var

Comment: am new to programming just trying programming with limited knowledge i have.. :D

Comment: @NikhilMishra - In that case can you better explain what you're trying to do and why you think this is an appropriate direction?  We can probably give you better advice then

Comment: @MarkKahn Ah, sure, forgive me for lack of info.

Comment: @MarkKahn I actually want it to link to an object to make things simpler. Instead of - 

b = new Bubble(200, 400, .....) , i was hoping to write - 
b = new Bubble(data); 

where data has x, y stuff in it.
function data() {
this.x = x,
}

or is there a more elegant

Comment: In that case you probably want to do something similar to what @RahmulSharma is suggesting and make your class have `constructor({x, y, z})` and call it with `new Bubble(data)`, assuming `data` is an existing object.  If you don't want to transpile code just pass in the object and make the constructor contain `this.x = data.x;`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var data;

function data() {
    this.x = 200,
        this.y = 200,
        this.r = 40
}


class Bubble {
    constructor({ 
        x,
        y,
        r
    }) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }
    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
        this.y = this.y + random(-5, 5);

    }
    show() {
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
    }
}
var b = new Bubble(new data());
```

I'm creating an object of data it'll be something like **{x:200,y:200,r:40}** will pass the same object to Bubble constructor, In the Bubble class constructor, It'll destruct coming object and assign it to x,y,z.

Comment: Please explain your solution in order to help the OP.

Comment: just an FYI to OP: this requires destructuring and thus transpiling code.  If you know what Babel is and use it that's fine.  If you don't then you probably don't want to go down that path just for this :)

Comment: check my comment, let me know it helps or not?

Comment: Thanks a million! :D I tried your code, it doesn't seem to work.. am getting this error _ Live reload enabled.
p5.js:47875 > p5.js says: ellipse() was expecting Number for parameter #0 (zero-based index), received string instead at http://127.0.0.1:3000/bubble.js:12:5. [http://p5js.org/reference/#p5/ellipse]_

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I actually want it to link to an object to make things simpler. Instead of - 

`b = new Bubble(200, 400, .....)`, i was hoping to write - 
`b = new Bubble(data);`
where data has x, y stuff in it.
`function data() {
this.x = x,
}
`
or is there a more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is an object, you have to pass `x`, `y` and `z` by calling them on  `data`, like this:

```
b = new Bubble(data.x, data.y, data.z);
```

But `data` is a function, so you have to call the function before and get it's result, like this:

```
var dataObj = new data();
b = new Bubble(dataObj.x, dataObj.y, dataObj.z);
```

Another thing, when you pass `data` to the `Bubble` constructor without parenthesis, you are passing a reference to the function `data`, so you can call it inside the constructor like this:

```
constructor(dataFn) { 
    var dataObj = dataFn();
    this.x = dataObj.x;
    this.y = dataObj.y;
    this.r = dataObj.r;
}
```

Comment: I agree, but imagine having too many arguments to pass, so thats why i was thinking to just have "data" For example - `code` b = new Bubble(data);

Comment: In this case, you'll have to take an object as the first paramter of your `constructor`. This object will have the same shape as `data`. Also, when you pass `data` without parenthesis to the constructor, you are passing a reference to the function, so, you can call it direclty in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as far as I understood you. You want initialize with `data` function. You can use `call`, or `apply`. Because you need to bind to `this` of class.

```js
class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, r) { 
    data.call(this); // it sets this.x, this.y etc
  }
  ....
}
```

However I presume, you probably want to give init value if your arguments were not initialized. So use default arguments.

```js
class Bubble {
  constructor(x = 200, y = 200, r = 40) { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks! Just to clarify this is what you are trying to imply - ` b = new Bubble();` ` class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, r) { 
    data.call(this);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }`

Comment: No you do not need ` this.x = x; this.y = y; this.r = r`. It will already assigned to this

Comment: One more thing. Let's say I have two bubbles. b1 = new Bubble(); and b2 = new Bubble(); I also have data1 for b1 and data2 for b2. How can I write this down?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your below code, the answer to ***IS THIS CORRECT?***

```js
var data;

function data() {
  this.x = 200,
  this.y = 200,
  this.r = 40,
}

b = new Bubble(data); **//IS THIS CORRECT?**
```

No. You are create a variable called `data` and the override it with a function. So you are passing a function. It should be an Object.

Another issue here is, variable `b` is defined without a declaration statement(`var|const|let`) This makes it a global variable in non-strict mode and error in strict.

---

2. `constructor(x, y, r) {` along with `new Bubble(data)` is also wrong. This will assign data to `x` and set `y` and `r` to default (`undefined`)

---

What you can do:

In constructor, you can use Object.assign, to assign the values received as object. You can also create an object with default value to make sure if any value is not passed, it is set to default.

Another benefit of using `Object.assign` is, it creates a copy of object. So if the object is mutated, it will not have any impact on your object.

**Sample:**

```js
class Bubble {
  constructor(params) {
    const defaultParams = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      r: 0
    }
    Object.assign(this, defaultParams, params)
  }
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
    this.y = this.y + random(-5, 5);
  }
  show() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }
}

const data = { x: 200, y: 200, r: 40 };
const data1 = { x: 150, y: 150, r: 50 };

const b = new Bubble(data);
console.log(b);

const b1 = new Bubble(data1);
console.log(b1);
```

Comment: @NikhilMishra Updated the sample.

Comment: I am getting this error - Uncaught ReferenceError: Bubble is not defined

Comment: Also why are u using const data type?

Comment: Since you do not want to mutate object, you can use const. If you are unsure, you can use `var` as well. Also about `Bubble`, make sure it is defined before you declare `new Bubble`